# How to make blender material preview lighting in unity

Tags: unity

Me and my brother are making a game and using blender and Unity. I create the models in blender and export them to his unity. We love the look and lighting of of the model in Blender's Preview lighting, Is there a way to achieve that same lighting and feel in in unity? We spent half an hour playing around with all lighting and materials, we couldn't get it right.